# How would you call someone/thing who adheres (or not) to a set of regulations?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, collective-nouns

Given a regulatory body of some form, what is the term for someone or something that adheres to those regulations?

I'm looking for a noun or collective noun, rather than an adjective.

An example sentence might be: "All of the X(s) must meet the regulations set out by the regulator.", where X is the generic term for one or all of these individuals or groups.

For example, in the electricity market in the UK, the regulator is called Ofgen, which provides regulations for all of these:

- Electricity Generators
- Electricty Distributers
- Electricty Suppliers

They don't necessarily have to be compliant to the regulations, so should be independent of that.

Ideas so far are:

- stakeholder(s)
- dependent(s)
- participant(s)
- partner(s)

but none sound specific in relation to the conformance with a set of rules.

This word is for formal use in a business document. A collective term would be ideal, but not essential.

Comment: Thank you for asking. Some information before we start will help us to give you the correct answer.
Please [edit] to add details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why.
Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage.
See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.

Comment: Your example sentence seems problematic, because IIUC there is nothing common to the Xs other than being subject to the regulations (as determined by the very same regulations). And saying *"All the entities subject to the regulations must meet the regulations set out by the regulator"* is rather meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

***[Compliant](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/compliant)*** may convey the idea:

> used to describe something that obeys a particular rule or law:
>
> - The company expects to be reclassified as soon as its factories are fully compliant with the Federal Clean Air Act.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: "Adherent" is another option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've clarified the question further. I'm not looking for a adjective, more of a collective noun. It doesn't need to indicate whether they are compliant or not, just that are guided by a set of rules.

Answer (score 1):

**conformists**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/conformist) noun

> A person(s) who uncritically or habitually conforms to the customs,
>   rules, or styles of a group

As in:

> "All conformists must follow the explicit regulations set out by the
>   regulator."